# Comparing a c-string and c++ string gives segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to add a Movie object to Movies only if Movie.name doesn't exist in the the Class Movies names_list (all movies in this category)
my code is

```
void Movies::add_movie(char name[], unsigned short rating, unsigned short watched_times)
{
        for (size_t counter{0}; counter <= (names_list.size() -1 ); ++counter)
        {
            if (names_list[counter] == name)    // Name is converted to c++ string
                cout << "Movie already exists " << endl;
            else {
                auto *x = new Movie{name, watched_times, rating};
                included_movies.push_back(x);
                cout << "Added movie " << name << " Successfully" << endl;
                names_list.emplace_back(name);
            }
        }
}
```

class definition is

```
class Movies {
private:
    char categery[20]{};
    vector <Movie*> included_movies;
    vector <string> names_list;

public:
    void list_movies();
    explicit Movies(char[]);
    ~Movies();
    void add_movie(char name[], unsigned short rating, unsigned short watched_times);
};
```

but each time running

```
comedy.add_movie("Alice in wonder land", 5, 1);
```

gives me a segmentation fault, so what is the problem exactly. Error originate in the if statement (one that do the comparison) so why.

### Edit

Someone noted that i was subtracting from size_t so that of course is not allowed so i tried to fix it and use a do-while loop but still the error exist 
the new code is but no difference too and error still in if statement execution

```
void Movies::add_movie(char name[], unsigned short rating, unsigned short watched_times)
{
        size_t counter{};
        do{
            if (names_list[counter] == name)    // Name is converted to c++ string
                cout << "Movie already exists " << endl;
            else {
                auto *x = new Movie{name, watched_times, rating};
                included_movies.push_back(x);
                cout << "Added movie " << name << " Successfully" << endl;
                names_list.emplace_back(name);
            }
            counter++;
        }while(counter <= names_list.size());
}
```

Comment: If you have a segmentation fault, you can inspect exactly what happened in the debugger.

Comment: `size()-1` of a `std::string` or a `vector` will end in tears when the string or the vector is empty. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: If `names_list` is empty, ask yourself what is the result of `counter <= (names_list.size() -1 )`

Comment: Also, don't you want to only add a new movie after checking the entire list?

Comment: Take note of the [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) construct, which avoids pitfalls like this...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks alot for this fix but even with casting for (size_t counter{0}; counter <= ( (short)names_list.size() -1 ); ++counter) the error still exists even with the new do while design above, so it seems independent of this

Comment: You're still casting to an unsigned, resulting in the same issue. As long as `counter` is unsigned, you can ***not*** meaningfully compare it to a negative value, and no matter which way you look, subtracting 1 from 0 gives a negative value. You will do yourself a favor if you become comfortable with using 0-based indexes, and always use `<` instead of `<=` for comparison: `counter < names_list.size()`. That seems much simpler and straightforward, and won't trigger this problem, don't you agree?

Comment: @ahmedamr You're still not handling the condition that the vector can be empty.  If the vector is empty, you can't do `if (names_list[counter] == name) ` as there is no value for `counter` that's legal when the vector has no elements.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik even if we ignore all this debugging code always result in normal execution it is the if statement that produce this error nothing is related to unsigned or signed of course it may produce an error in the the rest of the code but i mean code always break at if statement debugging made me see this

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks Nathan  didn't see your comment here so i need to first add a bool flag for the first item insertion then run the if stament right

Comment: or just use the right for loop syntax like `for (size_t counter{0}; counter < names_list.size(); ++counter)`.  Can you see how the loop wont run if the vector is empty now?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes that right Thanks a lot didn't think about that at all all this time i was searching for the error in the wrong place :)